# About stm32 timer : what is the difference between disable timer In the interrupt and disable timer outside the interrupt?

Tags: timer, stm32, difference

About stm32 timer : what is the difference between disable timer in the interrupt and disable timer outside the interrupt?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. The timer doesn't care whether the core is executing in "Thread mode" or "Handler Mode".

Thread mode is normal code execution, Handler mode is when an interrupt handler is running. These states are internal to the ARM core, and no peripheral is aware of this internal state.